# Create a hole in a polygon in Google Maps in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-flutter

I would like to make a hole in a polygon in flutter.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-hole

How can I reproduce the code in the above link in Flutter since the Polygon class doesn't take "paths" in its constructor but points?